# Oracle Context equivalent for DB2

Tags: oracle, db2, db2-luw

I am currently migrating from oracle to DB2. I have actively used sys_context in most of the applications to get the userID of logged in user through sessions(IIS and .net framework).

I am looking to convert the following set of scripts from oracle to DB2. So far not able to find any equivalent for oracle context in DB2.

```
SQL> create context my_ctx
  2    using pkg_ctx;

Context created.

SQL> create package pkg_ctx
  2  as
  3    procedure set_context;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_ctx
  2  as
  3    procedure set_context
  4    as
  5    begin
  6      dbms_session.set_context( 'MY_CTX', 'USERNAME', 'test' );
  7    end;
  8  end;
  9  /

Package body created.

SQL> exec pkg_ctx.set_context;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select sys_context( 'MY_CTX', 'USERNAME' )
  2    from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('MY_CTX','USERNAME')
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test
```

Comment: Is that similar to TRUSTED CONTEXT or to set the session user (both available in Db2)?

Comment: @data_henrik Not similar to TRUSTED CONTEXT. To be more precise, I have a sys_context in oracle from where I can retrieve the logged in application users stored in the session variables, session wise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you work with Db2 for LUW, you can use one of the [CURRENT CLIENT_*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008404.html?pos=2) registry variables to pass session context information from the client application to the server. For example, during the session initialization on the client side you would issue `SET CURRENT CLIENT_USERID='stacky'`, then on the server that variable can be read by a routine or a trigger.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out and will give an update.

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this, haven't tried it at application level. But from the database tried to register 2 users from 2 different instances of the same database on DB2.

```
call sysproc.wlm_set_client_info('stacky',null,null,null,null);
```

```
select wlm_set_client_info from  sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

returns stacky

from another instance of the same database

```
call sysproc.wlm_set_client_info('test',null,null,null,null);
```

```
select wlm_set_client_info from  sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

returns test.

Will try this from the application level through creating sessions of the users, will monitor how exactly this works with the special registers.

Not sure if this is the exact way to do this, will explore more and keep updated.

Answer (score 0):

For replicating a similar situation in our environment, while doing the migration from oracle to DB2 LUW.

The below procedure sets up the all the context values in user_id (limited to varchar 255) field which we need as as 'key1:value1|key2:value2|'

*Procedure to setup the  context values*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE setup_context(pValues        IN VARCHAR)
IS
lValues VARCHAR2(255) := pValues;
BEGIN
    --save the as is
    wlm_set_client_info(lValues, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
END;
```

*Procedure to set the value of the desired key*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sys_context(prefix IN VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR IS
    lValues VARCHAR2(255);
    lParam  VARCHAR2(255);
    lKey    VARCHAR2(255);
    lValue  VARCHAR2(255);
    lIndex  PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    --get the data from the current session
    SELECT CURRENT CLIENT_USERID INTO lValues FROM dual;
    
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN lValues IS NULL OR LENGTH(lValues) = 0;
 
        lIndex := instr(lValues, '|');
        IF lIndex > 0 THEN
            lParam  := substr(lValues, 1, lIndex-1);
            lValues := substr(lValues, lIndex+1);
        ELSE
            lParam  := lValues;
            lValues := NULL;
        END IF;
        lIndex := instr(lParam, ':');
        lKey   := substr(lParam, 1, lIndex-1);
        lValue := substr(lParam, lIndex+1);
        
       --get the matching value
        IF(lKey = prefix ) Then
            RETURN lValue;
        END IF;
    
    END LOOP;
   
   RETURN '';
END;
```

reference : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sp_wlmsetclientinfo.html